# Date of type of String in Delphi

Tags: string, date, delphi

We have a field in Access called 'DATE', in which the date is recorded, but is of the type Text.
Now, if we want to do a search, how is it possible with 'Between' statement ?
I use this code but it does not answer

```
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Text:= 'Select * From tst Where 1=1';
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add(' And Date1 Between ' +
  Date1.Format('yyyy/mm/dd',
  Date1.Date) + ' And ' + Date2.Format('yyyy/mm/dd', Date2.Date));
```

I think I need to convert string to date or number, but I do not know how

Comment: K.Fanedoul You can guide me

Comment: Easy, store it as a date to begin with, and you won't have to convert at all.

Comment: But I have to save it as text

Comment: That's an odd requirement, I wish you luck.

Comment: If you have to compare it as a string, and you've stored it as text in the form `YYYY/MM/DD` i.e. with leading `0` for the month and day then you can use a string comparison directly - i.e. `>=` and `<=`. If the date is not stored with leading `0` for the month and day, then you're going to find it difficult as there are a bunch of corner cases. This is not ideal, though!

Comment: It can be a success for me
Please help and guide @JerryDodge

Comment: Well first of all, how confident are you that these dates will always be in the same format of `yyyy/mm/dd`?

Comment: The only way storing your date as  a string can guarantee valid date data is to convert the string back to a date and check that it is valid before storing it in the db.  Which is a bit pointless when it *should* be stored as a date in the first place.

Comment: Because this format is not saved @JerryDodge

Comment: @narmafkar I think the point is that anything you do to solve this problem while resisting the idea of storing a date as a date will be a hack - it can't really be made robust or performant.  While you might get a workaround in an answer here, your long-term goal should be to refactor this table with a proper date field and, if absolutely needed, replacing the text column with a calculated field that converts from the date field which holds the actual data.

Comment: I'm not sure how your comment answers my inquiry. If anything, it supports it. The format is not saved in the database, so on another computer, which uses a different format, are you *absolutely sure* it will interpret it the same?

Comment: why do you have to store it as text ? That makes no sense. When it is a date type as it should be than the format how you show it is very easy to configure. Now you have tons of problems and you will get more into trouble as you keep developing with dates in text fields

Comment: You should also never build sql statements like this, use parameters. This is wide open for sql injection

Comment: @Guido:  Sorry, *what* exactly is wide open to Sql Injection?

Comment: @MartynA Building sql queries by concatinating strings. If any of the values comes from user input than it can be used for sql injection.

Comment: @GuidoG Just use QuotedStr around string parameters...

Comment: @HeartWare How will that stop sql injection ?

Comment: @GuidoG: "If any of the values comes from user input"  Indeed, that was why I asked,  AFAICS, none of the OP's expression *does* come from a user-inputted string, so it is hardly "wide open" to s.i..

Comment: @GuidoG - the string is constructed by formatting date values.  The only possible "injection" is a valid date, otherwise an exception due to an invalid date passed to the format function.  Building SQL by concatenation can be a vector for SQL injection but not all SQL concatenation provides such a vector.  There are other reasons for using parameterised queries but in this case SQL injection mitigation is not one of them.

Comment: @Deltics And OP's actual query might have a lot more going on which was excluded from this question, which *could* be vulnerable. It's certainly a good habit to always use parameters.

Comment: @Jerry - yes, they might.  And they *might* even be using parameters for those other things that are going on.  GuidoG's comments were nothing about what might "else" be going one, but specifically saying that "this" code was "wide open" to SI attack.  **This**code isn't, even if *similar* code might be.  The OP *might* also not be in a position to change the implementation details they are working with.  Instead of addressing what *might* be a problem, why not help with the OP's actual problem ?

Comment: @Deltics What's wrong with advising good practice to someone who might be unaware? Why the frantic rant against me? How is *that* productive? And FWIW, I *did* help with OP's actual problem. Did you read my first comment here (which you also advise in your answer)?

Comment: @Jerry - There's no anger or passion here.  No one's ranting.  Advising good practice is fine, but that isn't what GuidoG did - he said that *this* code, specifically, was wide open to attack.  And all I did was clarify MartynA's observation that this assertion is simply wrong, in *this* case.  "Best Practice" is not "dogmatically applying a *particular* practice in *all* cases even when not appropriate". *That* is cargo cult programming.  Explaining why a particular practice is not necessary in this case might in fact *help* the OP decide what practice is "best" in their specific case.

Comment: In defense of the OP using strings - I have a vendor that uses string format, for whatever reason, and the vendor isn't open to negotiating a change..if I told you the vendor, you'd say wow, it's no small company and known world wide.. so in some cases, we must do what we have to do..

Comment: @Deltics It seems my comment has been misunderstood. When I say `this is wide open for sql injection`I did not mean the exact code in the OP question, but I mean building queries like that without using parameters. I have once answered a question like this and in my answer build the string like the OP did and got downvoted because I did not give the advise to use parameters, even though that specific code did not received any user input. I wanted to give advise but I agree that how I wrote it can be misunderstood

Comment: @GuidoG It (QuotedStr) will stop sql injection by making sure that the SQL server does not see the entered text as commands, but as a literal string value.

Comment: @HeartWare and what with non varchar values ? This will work with the code from the OP that is true, but its not good practice to do it like that because when you create other queries that can be vulnarable he might still do it like this

Comment: @GuidoG Like I wrote: Just use QuotedStr around _string_ parameters. If the field in the database isn't a string, then don't use QuotedStr.

Comment: @HeartWare Exactly my point, if the field is not a string (varchar) then no QuotedStr and thus danger for sql injection

Comment: How? If the field is not a string, then it is (perhaps) an integer, and then you use IntToStr - again: No possibility for sql injection there... If it is a DateTime, then I use my DateTimeStrSQL (which only accepts a TDateTime as parameter, and not a string, and returns a string in the proper format for the underlying SQL server). If the user enters a date as a string, I convert it to a DateTime before I add it to the SQL string using my DateTimeStrSQL function, thus - once again - no possibility for sql injection.

Comment: @HeartWare I see what you mean. But what if you have to use a value for an int field that you need to get from TextBox1.Text for example. Are you sure every developer will use IntToStr() for this ? Its tempting to just concatinate TextBox1.Text when building the string.

Comment: @GuidoG Well, it takes discipline to do it by building the SQL string dynamically. In the particular case, I would never just blindly take the value. It would be trapped in my form validation code that the string was not a proper numeric value (like the DateTime above, which would also be validated before arriving at the SQL string), and thus would never exit the dialog as a string directly, but only as a (verified) integer. Thus the code that builds the SQL string would receive the value as an integer variable and would then need to use IntToStr to make the SQL string.

Comment: And yes - I *do* agree that the most safe way is to use parameters, but with a little discipline, it is certainly possible to use simple SQL string concatenation and still not be subject to SQL injection.

Answer (score 5):

As you say the field is text so values used in any `where` critera are expected to be text - i.e. strings.  Your encoded date values are not represented in the resulting SQL as a string, but as date literals, e.g.:

```sql
select * From tst Where 1=1
and Date1 Between 2018/01/01 and 2018/01/31
```

You need to use strings as the limits on your query (and also bear in mind that dates are quote delimited in SQL anyway, even when expressed as literals):

```sql
select * From tst Where 1=1
and Date1 between '2018/01/01' and '2018/01/31'
```

Assuming that the representation of the dates in your field are reliably consistent, this should work, thanks to the y-m-d ordering of your date components in that representation.

A small modification to your SQL construction code to include quotes around the encoded date values should do the trick:

```pascal
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text:= 'Select * From tst Where 1=1';
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add(' And Date1 Between ''' +
  Date1.Format('yyyy/mm/dd', Date1.Date) + ''' And ''' +
  Date2.Format('yyyy/mm/dd', Date2.Date) + '''');
```

This alternative approach to building the SQL might make it a little clearer exactly what is going on:

```pascal
// Obtain string representations of Date values
sDateFrom := Date1.Format('yyyy/mm/dd', Date1.Date);
sDateTo   := Date2.Format('yyyy/mm/dd', Date2.Date);

// Build SQL using string representations of dates in criteria
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text:= 'Select * From tst Where 1=1';
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add(Format(' and Date1 between ''%s'' and ''%s''', [sFromDate, sToDate]));
```

If you are in a position to change the implementation details of the database in your application, you should seriously consider using an appropriate date or date/time type for such columns which could simplify things when dealing with those columns and needing to work with them *as* dates or date/times, not least in then being able to use date/time related functions of your SQL engine directly on such columns, for example.

Also worth mentioning is that building SQL using string concatenation can make your code vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.  The specifics of this case mean that the code here is not vulnerable since the values involved are constrained to formatted date values, but this is a consideration and generally speaking parameterized queries are safer and can be significantly more efficient, especially where a query is re-used (executed several times) with only variations in the parameter values.

Comment: On a side note, `Where 1=1` is useless, unless multiple `where` conditions are added to the SQL dynamically and conditionally. In a hard-coded situation like this one, the `Where` should be on the `Between` statement instead: `ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'Select * From tst'; ADOQuery1.SQL.Add(Format('Where Date1 between ''%s'' and ''%s''', [sFromDate, sToDate]));`